# Ruby what does x[0...i] do

Tags: ruby

I do not understand this code:

```
a = [ "a!", "b!", "c!", "d!" ]
a.collect!.with_index {|x, i| x[0...i]}
a #=> ["", "b", "c!", "d!"]
```

On the `collect` line, what does `x[0...i]` do?  I see the output, but do not understand how it is doing/getting it.

Comment: Short answer: If `x` is a `String`, `x[0...i]` returns the first `i` characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html):

> Ranges constructed using .. run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using ... exclude the end value..

So `a..b` is like `a <= x <= b`, whereas `a...b` is like `a <= x < b`. ie:

```
>> "a!"[0...0]
=> ""
>> "a!"[0...1]
=> "a"
>> "a!"[0...2]
=> "a!"
```

---

In your `a.collect!.with_index`, the values of `x` and `i` will be:

- "a!" - 0 => `"a!"[0...0]` => `""`
- "b!" - 1 => `"b!"[0...1]` => `"b"`
- "c!" - 2 => `"c!"[0...2]` => `"c!"`
- and so on ...

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it had to do with ranges, but did not see it like you explained it.  Appreciate the reply.

Comment: You may wish to point out that `"c!"[0...2] #=> "c!"` is the same as `"c!"[0...n]` for all `n >= 2`.